# How to create reusable control in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig

How can I create a reusable panel based on http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels-heading in Symfony 2 and Twig? I mean how to create resusable control that I can embed in my twig page and provide to it header text and body, which will contain html and some other twig components (e.g. form controls).

This control should contain all the HTML that come from bootstrap panel example and I will only provide header text and body ... and control put this in appropriate place.

Answer (score 1):

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html

Are you talking about extending templates? That way you can reuse all the HTML that came from bootstrap and just overwrite the sections you need.

In Symfony2 the extends syntax is something like:

**somefile.twig.html**

`{% extends 'AcmeSomeBundle:Default:bootstrap.template.html.twig' %}`

Look at the documentation link above for more details.